# What is the "Burst" rule in Outlook 2011?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, automation, microsoft-outlook-2011

I am automating my workflow, and I found this action to be performed once the conditions of a rule are met:

[image: A screenshot of the "Do the following:" section of the Outlook rules dialog, with a dropdown with "Burst" selected, and an extended dropdown demonstrating that it relates to folders.]

However, several Google searches failed me, and I can't find out what "Burst" does. I haven't tested it, either, because maybe it "bursts" my emails into oblivion? Maybe it "burst"-fires this rule repeatedly? For safety, I want to know what it does, so... **what does "Burst" do?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never seen this option so I was curious! I found this:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/273018

> Burst Digests into Individual Messages - You can use this feature when
>   you subscribe to daily message digests. This feature breaks the digest
>   into separate and constituent messages. If you select this item, you
>   can specify that the original digest message is deleted after it is
>   burst.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_digest

> An email digest is an email that is automatically generated by an
>   electronic mailing list and which combines all exchanged emails during
>   a time period (e.g. day, week, month, etc.) or when a volume limit is
>   reached (e.g. every 10 or 100 messages) into one single message.

EDIT: Found the following too: http://www.oreilly.com/openbook/mh/burdig.htm

> When MH forwards message(s) with forw, or makes a digest with forw
>   -digest, it uses a special format called bit stuffing. That format makes it easy for the recipient to extract the "encapsulated"
>   messages, one by one. The MH burst command does this; it splits
>   (bursts) the group into separate messages. Recent versions of burst
>   also handle MIME-encoded digests (see the Section Forwarding in MIME
>   Format, forw -mime).

Comment: Ah, so it breaks apart auto-generated emails that were created from a mashup of several others, back into those others?

Comment: That is correct, see my edit for additional info.

Comment: Thanks! ... what's MH? I'm guessing it's an email server program?

Comment: MH is a bit special, it's an email client for command line that was first made in the 70s. MH was forked to NMH ( http://www.nongnu.org/nmh/ ) if you're intrested. Cchances are slim you'll enjoy using NMH unless you need to incorporate some mails in your scripts on a linux box  :)